# Is it possible to load external js ressources in a jade file?

Tags: javascript, pug

I would like to call google api and execute it inside a jade file. Is it possible to do something like this ?

Are there any equivalence for

```
     include myjs.jade
```

but something like this :

```
     include https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init
```

My purpose is not to include

```
    <script src'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init'/>
```

in my html but to call google shortner for helping me to construct my html before serving my html. ( In my html no need to use google shorturl).

In advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you want to inline the javascript? Why not just include it like you would any external JS resource in HTML?

```
script(src="<path to source>")
```

Comment: Hi, i dont' want to include this in my html. I would like to execute some code in my jade for helping me construct my content before serving ti to the server. ( I will add some details to my question)